# the dotnet sdk repo is set up wrong - how/where do I report it?

Tags: apt, 22.04, microsoft, dotnet

I don't know where to report this, if you could point me in the right direction that would be great.

**The question**, to be clear, is "Where do I report this," not "How do I solve this." I am including the report in case it helps differentiate whether this should be reported to Canonical, Microsoft, or to whatever org maintains Jammy.

### Steps to reproduce for dotnet sdk 6:

```
sudo apt-get isntall dotnet-sdk-6.0
which dotnet
dotnet --list-runtimes
dotnet --list-sdks
```

### Expected outcome for dotnet sdk 6:

- `which dotnet` lists a path
- `dotnet --list-sdks` lists dotnet 6
- `dotnet --list-runtimes` lists 1 or more runtimes

### actual outcome for dotnet sdk 6:

- `which dotnet` reports `/usr/bin/dotnet`
- `dotnet --list-runtimes` fails with `A fatal error occurred. The folder [/usr/share/dotnet/host/fxr] does not exist.`
- `dotnet --list-sdks` fails with `A fatal error occurred. The folder [/usr/share/dotnet/host/fxr] does not exist.`

### Before trying for dotnet 7:

Do `sudo apt-get remove dotnet*` `and sudo apt-get autoremove`

### Steps to reproduce for dotnet sdk 7:

```
sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-7.0
which dotnet
dotnet --list-runtimes
dotnet --list-sdks
```

#### Expected outcome

- `which dotnet` shows a path
- One or more dotnet 7 runtime is listed
- One or more dotnet 7.0 sdk is listed

#### Actual outcome

- `which dotnet` shows `/usr/bin/dotnet/
- Two dotnet runtimes are listed
- No dotnet sdk is listed

---

Mind you, these procedures *install* SDK 6 and 7 - I can find them in `/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/[6 or 7]` - but the dotnet binary doesn't find it.

Comment: Where did you get the dotnet SDK from?  Microsoft repositories, or Snaps, or some other method?